# Whitespace outside of html tags appearing on mobile chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, mobile

I have an issue with my website where whitespaces render outside the HTML tag borders on mobile. The issue is on mobile only and the same thing happens when the mobile chrome browser is set to desktop mode on mobile.

[Initial load mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J6gF.png)

This is how the website loads initially on mobile but the scroll is going way past the viewport of the HTML tags.

[Zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf1fU.png)

The thing I don't understand is the website removes the whitespace if the client rotates from portrait to horizontal and back.
As I use the same static template on all webpages the issue persists throughout the whole website.

The website is: [Zefir.codes](http://zefir.codes)

Website uses:

- [Animate (CSS Library)](https://animate.style/)
- [Bulma (CSS Library)](https://bulma.io/documentation/)

Heres the template for the static webpages:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A Hacker's world</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
     <a href="index.html"> <h1 class="title animated pulse">
        Zefir Repository <img src="img/logo.png" width="150px" height="150px" align="right">
      </h1>
      <p class="subtitle animated bounceInRight">
        A <strong>Hacker's</strong> World
      </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <br/>
  <div class="container is-widescreen">
<div class="tabs is-small animated lightSpeedIn">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Tutorials.html">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="me.html">About me</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<br/>

<!--Page Content-->
<div class="animated zoomIn">
<div class="container is-fluid">
<!--Column start-->
<div class="columns">
<!--first Column-->
  <div class="column is-one-quarter">

  </br>
  <p class="title">
Updates
</p>
<!--Notify03-->
<div class="card">
  <header class="card-header">
    <p class="card-header-title">
     A rebirth of the website!
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
    </a>
  </header>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="content">
    The website is coming back and strong!

      <br>
      <time datetime="2020-05-15">22:04 - 15 May 2020</time>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  <!--second Column-->
<div class="column">
</br>
<p class="title">
News
</p>
<div class="card">
  <header class="card-header">
    <p class="card-header-title">No News
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
    </a>
  </header>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="content">...
      <br>
      <time datetime="2017-12-6">8:23 PM - 15 May 2020</time>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  <div class="card">
  <header class="card-header">
    <p class="card-header-title">No news    </p>
        <a href="#" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">    </a>  </header>
        <div class="card-content">    <div class="content">... <br>
           <time datetime="2017-12-6">8:23 PM - 15 May 2020</time>    </div>  </div></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End of Content-->
</br>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content has-text-centered">
      <p>
        Zefir Repository is a collection of projects and tutorials by <strong><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/typicaljohan/">Jan Andersson</a></strong> Hosted on <strong>Infinityfree</strong>.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow-hidden` to the body of your website hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does this because your elements are positioned way to the right before the animation starts and the browser keeps this whitespace.
Either change your animation or a simple fix is to add:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```